# Extracting triplets from a sentence in Python

Tags: python-3.x, stanford-nlp

I am trying to extract triplets (subject - Predicate - object) from a given sentence using stanford dependency parser in Python. Can someone guide me through this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to the following links for triples extraction from sentences.

- https://github.com/tdpetrou/RDF-Triple-API
- http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html
- https://github.com/philipperemy/Stanford-OpenIE-Python