# Extract time interval entities from sentence

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to extract 3 pieces of information from a data set of a few thousand sentences in python. Specifically, for each sentence I would like to pull 1) the time interval ("interval"), 2) what the time interval is relative to ("relative_to"), 3) the name of the item or action the time interval is referring to ("item").

The use case is that I am trying to create something to tag these 3 items, so that I can use this is as training data to teach an NER model to do it well.

Here are 2 examples of sentences and the 3 pieces of info I would want from them:

Example 1:

```
sentence = "Not more than five (5) days following the Opening of Escrow, Seller covenants and agrees to conduct a review of its files and deliver to Buyer copies of any pertinent and material Due Diligence Materials (as defined in Section 13.2.4) in Seller's possession relating to the Property."

// expected extractions
interval = "five (5) days following"
relative_to = "the Opening of Escrow"
item = "Due Diligence Materials"
```

Example 2:

```
sentence = "The foregoing representations and warranties shall survive Closing for a period of one hundred eighty (180) days"

# expected extractions
interval = "one hundred eighty (180) days"
relative_to = "Closing"
item = "representations and warranties"
```

I can fairly reliably extract the interval using regex rules to look for words around digits and units.  However, I am having more difficulty extract the "relative_to" and "item" entities.

Previously on stack overflow I have seen posts like these that use a trained NLP model to tag the parts of speech, dependencies and named entities in the data to inform how once can extract them:
 - [Extracting triplets from a sentence in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002386/extracting-triplets-from-a-sentence-in-python)
 - [Extract entities from Multiple Subject passive sentence by Spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208346/extract-entities-from-multiple-subject-passive-sentence-by-spacy?rq=1)
 - [extract name entities and its corresponding numerical values from sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61258030/extract-name-entities-and-its-corresponding-numerical-values-from-sentence)

However, the tagging using spacy seem imprecise for locating the information I want from these sentences.

Is this still the approach that folks would recommend for my problem? Are there any other approaches you have tried that would work?

Thank you for any ideas you can share.